# is chrome faster because it doesn't reload images?

Tags: image, firefox, google-chrome

I have this issue for a while and I want to know if it is just me or it is the way chrome works. When I make changes to an image and upload it, on reload chrome fails to show the new image, instead it shows the old image. Firefox shows the new image. This happens mostly with big images, like background. So I have to wait for a few minutes before chrome shows the new image... Is this a rule or it happens just with my browser?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about what kind of questions you can ask here.

Comment: Before I posted I made sure that there are other questions concerning browser behaviour on this site. And this is a practical, answerable question for a problem that I face: chrome shows my new image only after many reloads...

Comment: @Claudiu: The question is better suited for superuser.com. You don't need to do anything, we'll migrate it for you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might happen because your local clock isn't synchronized with the web server. When you upload an image, a new file is created. The server will return the time stamp of the file when the browser asks for it. If that time stamp is older than what you have in your cache, the browser won't load the image again (assuming it's still good enough).

You should inspect the image (right click on it) and then look at the network activity. Chrome will tell you there whether it did load the image and why not.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's caching issue. This logic is different for different browsers.

You can clear Chrome cach by pressing Ctrl+Shitf+F12 and set option "Empty the cache". After this action new image should load always.